# How to use css styles in struts2 tags?

Tags: struts2

I am using metro CSS theme in my struts2 application. I was using html tags with CSS classes which was working fine. But while creating validation logic I found that It does validate the form but doesn't show any error.

```jsp
<form action="register.action" method ="post" validate="true">
 <div class="input-control text span3">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter User Name" value="" />
    <span class="helper"></span>
 </s:div> 
</form>
```

then I switched to struts2 html tags and it started showing errors but now I have no style attached. I used cssClass attribute of struts2 html tags to give style to form and div tags which worked well but after changing `<input type="text">` tag to `<s:textfield>` all the style attached to input box is gone.

Please suggest me how to use struts tags preserving CSS styles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already have all JSP-s with your own styles and elements use Struts2 `simple` theme. This theme will not create additional elements nor show validation errors. But you can use `fielderror` tag for showing validation errors http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/fielderror.html. So you form will look something like that:

```
<form action="register.action" method ="post" validate="true">
  <div class="input-control text span3">
    <s:fielderror fieldName="username"/>
    <s:textfield name="username" placeholder="Enter User Name"/>
    <span class="helper"></span>
  </s:div>
</form>
```

You can define default theme for the whole application inside your `struts.xml` file by using `struts.ui.theme` constant.

```
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
```

Comment: Thanks Aleksandr M, this is exactly what I was searching for. I got one more doubt, if I am using a non-field validation logic, It is not getting displayed by fielderror tag?

Comment: Also how can I use localization resource file keys to display label from ApplicationResource.properties?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `cssClass` property of `<s:textfield>` tag and add CSS styles to styleup your form.

```
<s:textfield cssClass="mytext" ... />

//css
.mytext {
}
```

One thing worth noting here is that Struts2 tag uses **xhtml** theme by default. Thus it generates lot of html code along with form. You may want to change the default theme to **css_xhtml** to apply your own styles instead of using Struts2 default.

Add following in `struts.properties` file.
    struts.ui.theme = css_xhtml

Reference: [Override Default Theme in Struts 2](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/struts-2-override-default-theme/)

Comment: This helped me. And oh, big fan of your tutorials :) Thanks a mil for those!