# how to display actionerror messages beside the field in struts while using xml validation

Tags: jsp, struts2, xml-validation, model-driven

here's what i did 
i have created a jsp page 
     cardholder

```
      <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
        <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
      <!DOCTYPE HTML>
         <%
     String client = (String) request.getAttribute("clientId");
      %>
       <html>
       <head>
     <style type="text/css">
      h3 {
       font-family: Calibri;
       font-size: 22pt;
      font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
color: SlateBlue;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: underline
 }

 table {
font-family: Calibri;
color: white;
font-size: 11pt;
font-style: normal;
text-align:;
background-color: SlateBlue;
border-collapse: collapse;
border: 2px solid navy;
text-align:;
}

   table.inner {
border: 0px
 }

  table {
margin: 0 auto;
  }
   </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function clear()
  {
  document.getElementsByName('custIdNum')[0].value = "";
  document.getElementsByName('passport')[0].value = "";
  document.getElementsByName('country')[0].value = "";
  document.getElementsByName('firstName')[0].value = "";
  document.getElementsByName('middleName')[0].value = "";
  document.getElementsByName('lastName')[0].value = "";
  document.getElementsByName('dob')[0].value = "";
  document.getElementsByName('officeNo')[0].value = "";
    document.getElementsByName('mobileNo')[0].value = "";
  document.getElementsByName('homeNo')[0].value = "";
  document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value = "";
  document.getElementsByName('postalId')[0].value = "";
  document.getElementsByName('address')[0].value = "";
  document.getElementsByName('state')[0].value = "";
  document.getElementsByName('city')[0].value = "";
  document.getElementsByName('clientNo')[0].value = "";
 }
 function changeStyle() {
    var v1 ="<%=client%>";
    if (!(v1 == "null")) {
        document.getElementsByName('clientNo')[0].value = v1;
        alert("client " + v1 + " registered successfully");
    }
  }
  </script>
  </head>

<body onload="changeStyle();">
<h3>Card Holder Details</h3>   
  <s:actionerror/>


<s:form action="registerClient">
    <s:div class="table">
        <tr><td><s:textfield name="clientNo" label="CLIENT ID" /></td></tr>
        <s:textfield name="custIdNum" label="CUSTOMER ID NUMBER" />
        <s:textfield name="passport" label="PASSPORT NUMBER" />
        <s:select name="country" label="NATIONALITY"
            list="{'BOTSWANA','NIGERIA','KENYA','S AFRICA','ZIMBABWE'}" />
        <s:textfield name="firstName" label="FIRST NAME" />
        <s:textfield name="middleName" label="MIDDLE NAME" />
        <s:textfield name="lastName" label="LAST NAME" />
        <s:textfield name="dob" label="BIRTHDAY" />
        <s:radio list="{'male','female'}" name="gender" label="GENDER"></s:radio>
        <s:textfield name="officeNo" label="OFFICE NUMBER" />
        <s:textfield name="mobileNo" label="MOBILE NUMBER" />
        <s:textfield name="homeNo" label="HOME NUMBER" />
        <s:textfield name="email" label="EMAIL ID" />
        <s:textfield name="postalId" label="POSTAL CODE" />
        <s:textfield name="city" label="CITY" />
        <s:textarea name="address" label="ADDRESS" />
        <s:textfield name="state" label="STATE" />
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><s:submit value="submit" theme="simple"/></td>
            <td><s:submit type="button" onclick="clear();return false;"
                    value="Reset" /></td>
        </tr>
    </s:div>
</s:form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

here is my xml validation file

```
      <!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator       1.0.2//EN"
      "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">
      <validators>
<field name="custIdNum">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <message>Customer ID is required.</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>    
<field name="passport">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <message>Passport Number is required.</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
<field name="firstName">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <message>Please Enter First Name.</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>    
<field name="lastName">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <message>Please Enter Last Name.</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
<field name="gender">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <message>Please select a gender</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
<field name="officeNo">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <message>Please Enter Office number.</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
 <field name="mobileNo">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <message>Please Enter personal mobile number</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
<field name="postalId">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <message>Please Enter Postal code</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
<field name="email">
    <field-validator type="email">
        <message>email required</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>

 </validators>
```

when i run this page i am getting error messages over the fields but i want to display them beside each field.
please help.

this is my action class

```
package com.struts.lifewardscard;
 import java.sql.CallableStatement;
 import java.sql.Connection;
  import java.sql.ResultSet;
 import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

 import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

 import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
 import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletRequestAware;
 import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;

  import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes;

  import com.struts.lifewardscard.CardHolderForm;
 import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
 import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;

 public class CardHolderRegistration extends ActionSupport implements   ModelDriven{

CardHolderForm cardform=new CardHolderForm();
public String execute() throws Exception{
    String clientId=null;
    HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    clientId=saveCardHolderDetails();       
    request.setAttribute("clientId", clientId);
    return "success";

}

@Override
public Object getModel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return cardform;
}
```

this is sample code generated after validation

```
  <tr errorFor="registerClient_custIdNum">
  <td align="center" valign="top" colspan="2"><span    class="errorMessage">Customer ID is required.</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td class="tdLabel"><label for="registerClient_custIdNum"   class="errorLabel">CUSTOMER ID NUMBER:</label></td>
 <td
 ><input type="text" name="custIdNum" value=""   id="registerClient_custIdNum"/></td>
 </tr>
```

i want the error display message to be on the same row as input row
not in a new row.

Comment: The error messages should display automatically unless you specified it in `struts.xml`.

Comment: Please edit your question by adding an example of the GENERATED html (from VIEW SOURCE) for one field and it's error message. Also note that this are FIELD errors, not action errors, and in the default XHTML theme they're already placed in the "right" place. If you want to change it, however, you should be able to do it with CSS alone, otherwise by using the SIMPLE theme and writing the code on your own

Comment: they are displaying fine but above the feild row i want them to be on the right side of the field  @Roman C

Comment: @AndreaLigios you are saying i can be able to do it with CSS alone can you please give me an example.

Comment: @AshokOgirala When you apply a theme on the form input field this theme will be used by the freemarker to choose a template corresponding to your desired markup. You should read how to create a custom theme on the struts site.

Comment: thanks a lot @RomanC i have looked into custom theme and i am able to display the messages inline with field.

Comment: @AshokOgirala I'm glad for you, hope you've read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13893498/573032) question too ;)

Answer (score 1):

> you are saying i can be able to do it with CSS alone can you please give me an example.

Almost everything can be done with CSS alone. In this case, however, it's not clean and has drawbacks (mainly due to the `colspan`), so two better alternatives are:

- **use the simple theme** and write the mark-up by yourself, like this:

  ```xml
  <s:textfield id="foo" key="foo" />
  <s:fielderror   fieldName="foo" />
  ```
- **create a custom theme**, forking the XHTML one and changing only the things you want to differ, like fieldError placement.

However, since you asked, and as a **pure academic exercise** (*don't try this at home*), here it is:

```css
table {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}
tr {
  background: #eee;
}
tr[errorFor] {
  color: red;
}
tr[errorFor]+tr {
  color: forestGreen;
}
#example1 tr[errorFor] {
  display: inline-block;
}
#example1 tr[errorFor]+tr {
  display: inline-block;
}
#example2 tr[errorFor] {
  float: right;
}
#example2 tr[errorFor]+tr {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr errorFor="registerClient_custIdNum">
    <td align="center" valign="top" colspan="2"><span class="errorMessage">Standard error label</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdLabel">
      <label class="errorLabel">Label</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdLabel">
      <label>foo</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      bar
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="example1">
  <tr errorFor="registerClient_custIdNum">
    <td align="center" valign="top" colspan="2"><span class="errorMessage">Inline-block error label </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdLabel">
      <label class="errorLabel">Label</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdLabel">
      <label>foo</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      bar
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="example2">
  <tr errorFor="registerClient_custIdNum">
    <td align="center" valign="top" colspan="2"><span class="errorMessage">Floating error label</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdLabel">
      <label class="errorLabel">Label</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tdLabel">
      <label>foo</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      bar
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```