# How to highlight fields which fail Struts2 validation?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, struts2

I have a user who would like to have the fields which fail Struts2 validation highlighted.

I plan to set a flag for any field which fails in my `validate()` method and use that field to change the background of the field when my JSP page is loaded.

My question is how do I handle the fields which fail the validation in my `Action-validation.xml` file ? Do I need to do all of my validation in my `validate()` method ?

Also is there a way to highlight the fields which generate an

> Invalid field value for field ...

error ?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature is already built in Struts2, no need for custom flags or whatever. In Struts2 form tags there is `cssErrorClass` attribute which will set CSS class for field on error.

```jsp
<style type="text/css">
    .errField {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>

<s:textfield key="name" cssErrorClass="errField" />
```

Comment: This worked great when I put the `<style>` code on my jsp page but it didn't work at all if I put `.errField{background-color:#ff6666;}` in my css file.  Is that normal?  Thanks!

Comment: Not at all: you are either not loading the right CSS, having it cached, having typos or getting into [specificity](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21728972/1654265) problems. I bet on cache.

Comment: I put the css in the same file which contains all of the rest of the css for the project so I think it is in the right place.  I tried the page with Firefox and it worked but it still doesn't work with IE so I think that supports your bet on cache.  I have restarted my computer and it still doesn't work.  How else do I clear the cache?  Thanks!

Comment: It was the cache.  I am running IE 11 and used F12->Network->Clear Cache (third Icon from the left).  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to do all of my validation in my `validate()` method ?

No

> How do I handle the fields which fail the validation in my Action-validation.xml file ?

Simply drop the flag idea, you're reinventing the wheel.

When a validation fails, no matter if it through annotation or XML, a fieldError is added. When instead you use the `validate()` method, you should add it by yourself.

The result, however, is the same: you'll have a fieldError with the name of every field not passing one or more validations.

Note that:

> Also is there a way to highlight the fields which generate an
>
> > Invalid field value for field ...
>
> error ?

those are *conversion* errors. They're added by the Conversion Interceptor ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23450365/1654265)).

In the end, no matter if XML, `validate()`, conversion or whatever, every kind of fielderror will be in that object, that is a

```
Map<String,List<String>>
```

because every field could have multiple errors.

You can iterate that map in the page to highlight the related fields through Javascript (or even CSS, when using the `simple` theme, because [with the other themes is just a mess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32861577/1654265)).

For example:

```xml
<style>
    .highlightedError {
        border: 2px solid red;
    }
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){
        <s:if test="hasFieldErrors()">
            <s:iterator value="fieldErrors">
                var currentFieldError = '<s:property value="key" escapeJavascript="true" />';
                $('[name="'+currentFieldError+"']").addClass('highlightedError');
            </s:iterator>
        </s:if>
    });
</script>
```