# Applying bootstrap styles to Struts 1.x html tags

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, struts-1, struts1

I am working on some legacy Struts 1.x applications that use Struts html tags instead of standard html tags. I am trying to modernize the UI without making functional changes.

For example:
The input field is `<html:text property="someProperty" styleClass="someCssStyle">`

instead of `<input type="text" class="someCssStyle">`

If I change, `<html:text>` to `<input type="text">` the property binding breaks i.e. the value in input field is not passed to the code.

If I try to apply bootstrap styles to `<html:text>`, it does not work.

How can I apply Bootstrap styles to legacy struts html tags?

Comment: is styleClass ="form-control" not working

Comment: No. It does not apply the rounded edge style associated with <input> to <html:text>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893498/how-to-use-css-styles-in-struts2-tags

Comment: That question and accepted answer both are Struts 2 specific and will not work for Struts 1.x.

Comment: 1) Is it possible to suround the element with a wrapping div for example? 2) Can the solution include javascript / jQuery? 3) can you provide an example of how the field looks in html when it is rendered?

Answer (score 2):

You have add the style(s) to the `styleClass` attribute.

For example:

```
<html:text property="propName" name="formName" styleClass="form-control"></html:text>
```

or

```
<html:submit styleClass="btn btn-link">submit</html:submit>
```

Here is a very basic sample app on GitHub that shows this working:
https://github.com/lviviani/sample-struts-bootstrap