# I have one requirement in which I need to print a web page(actually a jsp page created using struts 1.3 ) using brower's print option

Tags: java, html, css, struts-1

I have one requirement in which I need to print a web page(actually a jsp page created using struts 1.3 ) using browser's print option in such a way that buttons which are there on that webpage should look little darker in print or in pdf(when we use save as pdf).

I had tried below code inside head tag:

```
<style>
  @media print { 
    .light {color: #000 !important; }
  }
</style>
```

I put the buttons inside a div and tried to apply .light class on that dive so that only during print or saving it as pdf buttons should be visible darker.

buttons code is as below (struts bean tag is used here):

```
     <div class="light">
       <bean:message key="button.internet.request.update" />
     </div>
   <% } %>
   </html:submit>
 <% } %>
```

so I added line no. 1 and 3 just for putting the button code inside a div and applied that .light class. But it didn't work.
Help me appling the css code in bean tag so that button gets printed darker on print page or visible darker in pdf.
Images for proper button and disturbed button I have attached. Proper here means before applying my code and disturbed one is for after applying my code which didn't work.

[image]

Comment: to change button color you must use css parameter "background-color" also changing div color won't change button color.

Comment: only button border and text written on button I need little darker on print page, but I don't want any change of look and feel of the button on webpage. Only during print I want this change. pls suggest how I can apply this css class with struts bean tag which is used for buttons.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893498/how-to-use-css-styles-in-struts2-tags